# Is it possible to run unit-tests with sonar-runner?

Tags: maven, unit-testing, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am just learning about unit-testing with *SonarQube*. From my current understanding running unit-tests requires the use of *Maven*. I was following this helpful tutorial: http://www.sonarqube.org/unit-test-execution-in-sonarqube/ which explains how to display unit-tests results on the *SonarQube* dashboard. This works if there are relevant Java source-files in the `test` directory. However, I was wondering if there is a way to do the same thing with `sonar-runner` instead of `mvn`. Does anyone out there know?

Thank-you for reading this.

Respectfully,

user

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are running unit test in Java.

What the sonar-java plugin does is only importing junit report generated by surefire. So you have to run your tests (with maven or whatever build tool you want) and then let the sonar analysis (run with maven or sonar-runner) import them in SonarQube.

It is not the responsability of sonar-runner to run your tests.

Comment: Thank-you for the reply. :D Yes, these unit-tests are for Java source-code. So what you are saying is that I 1) run the unit-tests with `mvn` and then 2) import these results with `sonar-runner` onto the web interface?